# Vuejs and Page Refresh on <router-link> click

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to make a page refresh after I click on the router-link. How can I do that with Vue JS in Laravel? but I don't want to use `onclick="window.location.reload();"`

My code is something like that-

Code in app.js

```
{
    path: '/publisher',
    component: require('./components/Publishers.vue').default,
  }
```

Code in Master.blade.php

```
<li> <router-link to="/publisher" class="nav-link"  >انتشارات</router-link></li>
```

Code in publishers.vue

```
export default {
  components: {  
  },
  data() {
    return {
     
      Publishers: {},
     
    };
  },
  computed: {},
  methods: {    
    loadPublishers() {
      this.$Progress.start();
      axios.get("api/publisher").then(({ data }) => (this.Publishers = data));
    },
  },

  created() {
    this.loadPublishers();
    // load the page after 3 secound
    Fire.$on("refreshPage", () => {
      this.loadPublishers();
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: _"I don't want to use `onclick="window.location.reload();"`"_  why not?

Comment: I want to know what is used for  it in vue

Comment: Vue is an un-opinionated UI framework. There is no _"Vue version"_ of this sort of action. You can use whatever works

Comment: I have never used Laravel in my life and don't know anything about data table UI components.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a `name` property to the `route` object and instead of using `<router-link>`, you can use an `a` tag like this

```
<a :href="$router.resolve({name: 'publisher'}).href">link</a>
```

Your route object will be like

```
{
    path: '/publisher',
    name: 'publisher',
    component: require('./components/Publishers.vue').default,
}
```

The name field in the `router` is not mandatory, it is using only for making it simple to use.

Comment: Please check this link : https://matanya.gitbook.io/vue-tables-2/ or you can try datatable in Vuetify (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/). I always use custom tables for my purpose ;)

Comment: Using `a` with `$router` works great (+1). It **passes original route parameters** as well. However, if different or additional parameter is required, use `params`, eg: `<a :href="$router.resolve({name: 'routeName', params: {id: anotherId} }).href"`